# ParticleJS is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been having some issues trying to get the 'Particle.JS' to work. When checking the console, it says "ParticleJS is not defined", but I defined the id as 'particles'. Very grateful for the help, in future ref.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="canvas">
        <div id="particles">
           <h1>We Love <span class="rotate">Simple, Responsive, Minimal, Fun</span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
```

```
.wrapper h1 {
      font-size: 55px;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin-top:15%;
    }

.canvas{ width:100%; height:95%; background:url(../img/banner.jpg) center; background-size:cover; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}

#particles {z-index: 4;height: 100%;height: 100vh;}
```

```
particlesJS('particles', {
  particles: {
    color: '#fff',
    color_random: false,
    shape: 'triangle', // "circle", "edge" or "triangle"
    opacity: {
      opacity: 1,
      anim: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 1.5,
        opacity_min: 0,
        sync: false
      }
```

Comment: is your code placed after particles.js loads? And is particles js even loading?

Comment: First check `js/particles.js` file loads correctly or not. In chrome you can inspect element and go to `Sources` tab. or if you are connected to internet try `<script src="http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/particles.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you man! When I switch it to 'particles.min.js', it started working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you must be  initialize your `particle.js` script first, then only you initialize another scripts